# Exporting multiple Highcharts that are generated by looping to a single pdf

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I had created certain polar charts and is in a requirement to export all to a single pdf. 
These polar charts was rendered to the same container within some interval. So I used setInterval with 3sec interval and populated the charts inside setInterval method. Now I have a requirement to export all those 12 charts to a single pdf.

```
var i=0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
            let data1= [];
            let data2= [];
            let data3= [];
            let datetime= [];
//These arrays are filled with some logic in this part
            this.populateFiveMinSpider(data1,data2,data3,datetime);
            i++;
            if(i === 12) {
                clearInterval(interval);
             }
         }
     }, 3000)
 }
```

I tried saving each of the chart to local after it loads and then combining all local files to one pdf from server side(java) in a 'download' button click.
But that just creates a file in local without downloading in button click. And also after each chart loading the download bar occurs which is visible, that doesnot justify the requirement.

```
 events: {

            load: function () {
                var chart = this;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        // EXPORT THE CHART HERE
                        chart.exportChart({
                            type: 'application/pdf',
                            filename: 'my-pdf'+date,
                            sourceWidth: 1100,
                            sourceHeight: 600,
                            scale: 1,
                        });
                    }, 1000);
                }
        }
```

This code was used to download inidvidual pdf.
Then I tried to get pdf without downloading with getPDF() method.

Help me out to download these files in one button click. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: can you add some more code or fiddle here

Comment: Sry.i cant share code. I have one more doubt..what is the difference between ('#container').highcharts() and new Highcharts(). because im getting Highcharts not found when using the second method.

Comment: please refer this documentation https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart

Comment: my doubt is not clarified in this.There are two ways of rendering a chart.One is ("#container").highcharts(....... Another is - new Highcharts.Charts(...... What is the difference in these. Can you help me clarify since wherever I type Highcharts, it is not accepted.

Comment: `("#container").highcharts();` in this `#container` is id of your chart div. This chart will be generate from data directly, sorry for your question I check and let you know. Otherwise can you create sample jsfiddle and add sample code

Comment: thats ok.. what is the difference in rendering chart in these two ways. Both gives the same result, but the new Highcharts(.... method needs any extra configuration in angular2+

Comment: which version of angular you are using? reference for highcharts with angular https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/highcharts-angular-wrapper/ and https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#options-details

Comment: angular2 im using. version 2.0.0

Comment: if you create any sample fiddle [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/), it will be easy to resolve and also we can understand your question more. Highcharts complete documentation is here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/index

Comment: Actually im accessing highcharts with cdn. So im able to use ("$container").highcharts.. But when using Highcharts keyword in project, it cannot be found. So not able to do - new Highcharts(.... kind of implementation. Using angulr2 when i search everyone comments of highcharts-angular. But im using normal highcharts with angular2. Im confused of the import statements of highcharts module. That how to configure normal highcharts using cdn for angular2 project. is it possible

Comment: did you imported all plugins properly?

Comment: These are imported plugins: <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script> What are the other configurations needed in angular2?

Comment: but you are not using `highcharts-angular` in your plug in, can you please check this https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#installing

Comment: no. im not using highcharts-angular. is there any way I can continue without highcharts-angular

Answer (score 2):

The whole process can be done by JavaScript. You can create some layout of charts in SVG and then export it to PDF:

```
$('#export-pdf').click(function() {
    Highcharts.exportCharts([chart1, chart2, chart3, chart4], {
        type: 'application/pdf'
    });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v0p6hce8/

**Useful thread:** https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40493

Comment: Im using angular2.0.0 and getting highcharts from the cdn included in script. Since I dont have highcharts-angular module included, Im not able to use the "Highcharts" keyword. Im plotting graphs $("#container-name").highcharts(..... in this format which is working. Is there any way I can implement the same requirement without using "Highcharts" keyword. Since I tried installing highcharts-angular and where having dependency issues.

Comment: Hi @LEKSHMI SURESH, I am not an Angular expert, but I think that you should use the official Angular wrapper for Highcharts: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular

Comment: Do all versions of  Angular wrapper for Highcharts support this exportcharts functionality?

Comment: @LEKSHMI SURESH - I think that the answer is yes - you need to only add and initialize `exporting` module.